# Electric switch

Tags: wiring, light

My light switch in the family room and garage light switch is on the same circuit, so if I put on the family room light the garage light has to be on and vice versa. How can I split them to work independently?

Comment: We're going to need some pictures of the switches and the boxes.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Comment: I can't understand what *vice versa* means in this context.

Comment: Are both switches in the same location? If they are someone goofed when the switch was replaced. You will need to identify the incoming hot this needs to be connected to both switches. My guess is at some point the switches were updated and the wires were reversed.